# what's difference , to launch from 'Notifications' and launcher icon?

Tags: android, android-notifications

My `MainActivity` is overriding `onNewIntent`.
And myService is foreground service with Notification.

After myprogram is killed,
If i launch my program from `launcher icon`, `onNewIntent` is called finally.
But if i launch from `Notification`, `onNewIntent` is never called.

I think stack is different.
What do you think?

My Notification from myService class is like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,InputMainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.notiicon,"comment",System.currentTimeMillis());
                    n.setLatestEventInfo(myService.this,"comment",“comment“,pi);
startForeground(1,n);
```

How should i do to call onNewIntent when this program is called from Notification?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with this code?

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```